# Generating complementary DNA sequence

Tags: python, beginner

I am still relatively new to Python but I have been actively doing sample examples to try and get used to problem solving aspect of programming.

With that said, I stumbled upon a question that asks you to write a code to convert DNA strand to its complementary form.

What I have written works, but I don't believe that my approach is efficient enough. Could you please review my code and guide me as to how I might improve on it? I feel like there will be a faster way than writing multiple if, elif statements.

```
import sys

def check_input(user_input):
    if len(user_input) == 0:
        sys.exit("No strand provided.")
    return user_input

def complementary(strand):
    complementary_strand = ''
    for dna in strand:
        if dna == 'A':
            complementary_strand += 'T'
        elif dna == 'a':
            complementary_strand += 't'
        elif dna == 'T':
            complementary_strand += 'A'
        elif dna == 't':
            complementary_strand += 'a'
        elif dna == 'G':
            complementary_strand += 'C'
        elif dna == 'g':
            complementary_strand += 'c'
        elif dna == 'C':
            complementary_strand += 'G'
        elif dna == 'c':
            complementary_strand += 'g'
        else:
            complementary_strand += 'x'
    return complementary_strand

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_input = input("Enter strand: ")
    print()
    strand = check_input(user_input)
    complementary_strand = complementary(strand)
    print("Complementary strand is {}".format(complementary_strand))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically, a character-for-character replacement is best done using [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
strand.translate(str.maketrans('AaTtGgCc', 'TtAaCcGg'))
```

However, your situation is trickier, because you also want to map all invalid characters to `'x'`.  To achieve that, you would need to read the [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) documentation carefully, and figure out that you can wrap the mapping in a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict

DNA_COMPLEMENTS = defaultdict(lambda: 'x', str.maketrans('AaTtGgCc', 'TtAaCcGg'))

def complementary(strand):
    return strand.translate(DNA_COMPLEMENTS)
```

Note that `lambda: 'x'` is a way to make a function that, when called with no parameters, returns the letter `'x'`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but considering the amount of views it gets (and I also looked it up now) thought I'd also add.

Couldn't you just use a dictionary, and convert all letters to upper (this way you don't have to import anything either)?

```
DNA_complement_dict={'A':'T',
                     'T':'A',
                     'G':'C',
                     'C':'G'

def check_input(user_input):
    if len(user_input) == 0:
        sys.exit("No strand provided.")
    return user_input.upper()

def complementary(strand):
    complementary_strand = ''
    for dna in strand:
       try:
         complementary_strand += DNA_complement_dict[dna]
       except:
         complementary_strand += 'X'
    return complementary strand
```